# How to send email from noreply@mydomain.com with GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps

`mydomain.com` is Google Apps linked to my GAE application (and verified). Currently only one user is allowed at custom domains, so I've registered `admin@mydomain.com`. Now, I would like to send emails from `noreply@mydomain.com`. I try to add this user as Developer in Permissions section of my GAE application, it sends the message (which I actually receive at `admin@mydomain.com`), I accept the invitation as `admin@mydomain.com`, but it doesn't help.

So, how to send emails from `noreply@mydomain.com`?

Comment: what if you add one user using the trial and then deleting that user (after accepting the invitation)

Comment: @Lipis, trial of Google Apps for Business?

Comment: yep.. unless you already used it.. ;) I think (at least back in the good old days) you would roll back in the free version... not sure how it work now..

Comment: This is one of the reasons, I am using Amazon SES as a webservice for sending mail from GAE

Comment: @Lipis, please post your comment as the answer, so I will be able to accept it - it helped.

Comment: @LA_ Hey.. was on long vacations and a bit away from the Internetz..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable the trial (lasts for 30 days) and add as many users as you want. You can send emails to them to accept the invitations in GAE and after accepting them you can delete these users to fall back in the free version with only one user.

Comment: Hmm.. Finally I've deleted all users and returned back to free Google Apps version and.. it deleted all my authorized users :(

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to test the below, as I don't have the new single account Google Apps.

It all depends on if you still want the admin@domain.com user. If not I suggest the following;

- For safety link a non-domain email as an owner to your App Engine application
- [Rename](https://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182084) your current Google Apps user from admin to noreply

You should be able to send emails as noreply@domain.com.

If you still want admin@domain.com, maybe you can create an [alias](https://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33327) for the noreply account?

Comment: Surely I want to keep admin@domain.com. The approach with alias doesn't work since I should be able to login under this email and it doesn't work with alias.